# Spring Boot 2 milestone is unable to pick values from application.properties

Tags: spring-boot

I am using the milestone branch of Spring Boot (2.0.0.M7) with Gradle.
I have some set of values in application.properties

```
app.name=MyApp
app.description=Hello from MyApp
app.version=1.0
```

In my application-DEV.properties I have

```
app.version=1.0-DEV
```

In my SpringBootApplication i am injecting the value as

```
@Value("${app.name}")
private String name;

@Value("${app.version}")
private String version;
```

I put application-default.properties in the current dir which has following data

```
app.version=1.0-DEVX
spring.profiles.active=DEV
```

When I run my SpringBootApplication from IDE, it works fine.
But when I build jar and run it as java -jar MyApplication.jar it gives an error

> Could not resolve placeholder 'app.name' in value "${app.name}"

It works fine if i replicate all the values into application-default.properties or in application-DEV.properties.
It also works fine if i use Spring Boot 1.5.9-RELEASE or older.

I dont see any documentation that the profile overrides have changed.  Maybe its a bug?

Comment: Can you explode your jar and make sure your properties file is making it in?

Comment: Yes its in there in application jar!/BOOT-INF/classes

Answer (score 0):

There was an application.properties that was packaged in another jar which was causing this issue. After removing the application.properties from that jar, it works as intended.